Subject + gerund question
I found the text below in a comment posted on the video for Taylor Swift's new song "Fortnight" (feat Post Malone) on YouTube. In one part of the video she (Taylor Swift) appears with her face almost completely covered with tattoos, as is his, and in another part he (Post Malone) appears with his face without any tattoos.
Here's the comment I'm referring to:
I loveeee the tattoo symbolism. Her having his tattoos shows that he rubbed off on her and her not seeing his tattoos shows that she sees the person under them.
I assume that the expressions "her having his tattoos" and "her not seeing this tattoos" respectively mean something like "the fact that she has his tattoos" and "the fact that she doesn't see his tattoos" - although I'm not completely sure from that.
However, assuming this is correct, is this type of expression ("her having his tattoos" and "her not seeing this tattoos") common in English? This type of grammatical construction does not exist in Portuguese (at least not literally) and I had never encountered this type of expression even in English before.

Should be a duplicate When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund
